# Quiero cambiar un elemento en especifico de un array de MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Hola tengo un documento en MongoDB con ciertos tipos de datos, uno de ellos es un array de objetos de alumnos y quiero cambiar la nota de uno de ellos.

El problema es que hay varios grupos con diferentes alumnos cada uno, para especificar el grupo uso la id, pero no se como apuntar al indice del array de los alumnos para cambiar la nota

esta es la estructura:

```
{

pruebas:Array
alumno_completed:Array
 0:Object
  id: "id_random"
  full_name:"Roberto"
  DNI:"1234"
  calification:0
preguntasHechas:Array
group:"Grupo superior A"
asignatura:"botanica"
isClosed:false
}
```

en este caso solo hay un alumno que es el de prueba, pero ¿comó hago si en ese array hay muchos alumnos?

este es el codigo que uso para cambiar la nota pero esta mal:

```
await Questions.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id.slice(1),
    {
        $set: {
            alumno_completed.[index].calification: 1
        }
    });
```

El index es al indice que en el que apunto al array

Comment: Eso lo puedes encontrar en la [documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/write-operations/embedded-arrays/)

Comment: Tienen buenos ejemplos, pero en mi caso en concreto no me sirve de mucho, ya que tengo que cambiar un elemento, no añadirlo como uno de los ejemplos de la documentación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola encontre una forma de solucionar mi problema de la siguiente manera

primero tomo el documento de la base de datos, luego obtengo el indice en el que quiero guardar la información y con el siguiente codigo lo guardo

```
question.alumno_completed[index].calification = total_calification;

await Questions.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id.slice(1), {
        $set: {
            alumno_completed: question.alumno_completed
        }
```

Si alguien tiene una manera más eficiente de hacerla, siempre es bienvenida!